# How to align the spark button?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

This is the scenario:

```
<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout verticalAlign="top" horizontalAlign="center" paddingTop="30"/>
</s:layout>
<s:states>
    <s:State name="Login"/>
    <s:State name="Register"/>
</s:states>
<s:Panel id="loginPanel" title="Login Form" title.Register="Registration Form" height="400" width="300" color="Black">   

    <s:Form top="0" bottom="0"
            left="20" right="0">
        <s:FormItem label="First Name:" includeIn="Register" color="White">
            <s:TextInput id="firstName" color="Black"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Last Name" includeIn="Register" color="White">
            <s:TextInput id="lastName" color="Black" />
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Email:" includeIn="Login, Register" color="White">
            <s:TextInput id="email" color="Black" />
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Password:" includeIn="Login, Register" color="White">
            <s:TextInput id="password" color="Black" displayAsPassword="true"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Conform:" includeIn="Register" color="white">
            <s:TextInput id="confirm" color="Black" displayAsPassword="true"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem >
                <s:Button label="Need To Register" id="needToRegister" includeIn="Login" click="currentState='Register'" left="0"/>
                <s:Button label="Return To Login" id="returnToLogin" includeIn="Register" click="currentState='Login'"/>
                <s:Button label="Login" id="login" 
                          label.Register="Register" click="loginFun()" 
                          click.Register="register()"/>

            </s:FormItem>
    </s:Form>
```

And the question is how to align the buttons in horizontal order? I tried with HGroup. But the buttons are not justified when we use HGroup. If anything else is there, please share with me.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I done it.

```
            <s:FormItem >
                <s:layout>
                    <s:HorizontalLayout gap="30" paddingLeft="-15"/>
                </s:layout>

                <s:Button label="Need To Register" id="needToRegister" 
                          includeIn="Login" />
                <s:Button label="Return To Login" id="returnToLogin" includeIn="Register" />
                <s:Button label="Login" id="login" 
                          label.Register="Register"/>

            </s:FormItem>
```

Now its working. But i don't know. This is a right way. Can anyone tell me this is a good way or not?

Comment: What do you see currentlY? I did not understand your question, If you add a hgroup the buttons will be ordered in horizontal fashion. You want the buttons to wrap to the next line?

Comment: Hello Zeus. I want to display my button in the next of the label. When I am using HGroup or HorizontalLayor, I will display the button after the TextBox.

Comment: which piece of code are you referring to ?

Comment: HorizontalLayout with padding.

Comment: Hello Zeus.I think now you can understand what I am telling. And can you tell me this is right or wrong?